# Error restarting networking service

Tags: ip, debian-bullseye

I am trying to set both a static ipv4 address and a static ipv6 address on a home hosted Debian 11 server (it's actually just a PC).

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.149
    netmask 24
    gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eno1 inet6 static
    address 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1234
    netmask 56
    gateway fe80::712a:e39b:d35a:3ea4
```

After restarting networking service with `sudo service netowrking restart"
Here is the result (exactyly what i want):

```
sept. 15 00:07:56 omen-debian systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
sept. 15 00:08:07 omen-debian ifup[785]: Waiting for DAD... Timed out
sept. 15 00:08:07 omen-debian ifup[637]: ifup: failed to bring up eno1
sept. 15 00:08:07 omen-debian systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sept. 15 00:08:07 omen-debian systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sept. 15 00:08:07 omen-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:d3:ff:e6:b5:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp5s0
    inet 192.168.1.149/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1234/56 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cad3:ffff:fee6:b559/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you see my networking service produces an error.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: try to disable IPv6 DAD (Duplicate Address Detection) `net.ipv6.conf.<interface name>.accept_dad = 0`

Comment: @asktyagi Solved it for me, looks like the DAD timeout is too long for systemd to wait?

Answer (score 1):

*this is @asktyagi answer but I added here to be clear to others*

On Debian 11 , after booting, `systemctl status networking.service` would show failure to add ipv6 addr to an interface that had ipv4 addr.
Even it was set to `/etc/network/interface` that interface did not have ipv6 address

```bash
Jan 30 14:07:48 debian11 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jan 30 14:07:48 debian11 ifup[543]: RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied
Jan 30 14:07:48 debian11 ifup[478]: ifup: failed to bring up ens192
```

so the error is *RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied*

#### none of these worked

```bash
ip -6 addr add IPv6/64  dev ens192 metric 1
```

and showed *permission denied*

then

```bash
route -A inet6 add IPv6/64  dev ens192
```

was also showed *permission denied*

changing `/etc/sysctl.conf` with these options did not solved [link](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/adding-ipv6-address-does-not-work-error-message.282873/)

```bash
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0

# and
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

or reordering the configuration did not help either [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578578/171868)

#### worked

```bash
net.ipv6.conf.<interface name>.accept_dad = 0
```

and reboot.
After reboot there was no error on networking and ipv6 was added to the interface.